# While drawing a rectangle in html canvas using mouse the rectangle is always out of placement

Tags: typescript, canvas, mouseevent, svelte

In the below code I am trying to create a canvas over the webpage then use the canvas to draw shapes like rectangle using the mouse events. Since the canvas is placed on the top left corner there is no offset for mouse positions. But still I am not able to coordinate the mouse position with the rectangle that's been drawn . Both the rectangle and the Mouse are always out of placement. I am trying to implement this in svelte.

```
var startX=0;
    var startY=0;
    var mousex = 0;
    var mousey = 0;
    var mousedown = false;
    var width: number;
    var height: number;
    var offsetX=0;
    var offsetY=0;
    var scrollX=0;
    var scrollY=0;
    // make var color a global variable
    var color = 'black';

    // Capture screenshot of a specific area
    function captureScreenshot(x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
            .then((stream) => {
                const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
                const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
                videoElement.srcObject = new MediaStream([videoTrack]);

                videoElement.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                    const videoWidth = videoElement.videoWidth;
                    const videoHeight = videoElement.videoHeight;

                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;

                    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    context?.drawImage(videoElement, x, y, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);

                    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                        const screenshotUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob as Blob);

                        // Open the screenshot in a new window/tab
                        window.open(screenshotUrl);

                        // Clean up the resources
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(screenshotUrl);
                    }, 'image/png');

                    // Stop the video stream and clean up resources
                    stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
                };

                videoElement.play();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('An error occurred while accessing the screen:', error);
            });
    }

    //Handle mouse event
    const handleMouseDown = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        const canvas = document.getElementById('snip') as HTMLCanvasElement;
        offsetX = canvas?.offsetLeft as number;
        offsetY= canvas?.offsetTop as number;
        startX =  event.clientX - offsetX;
        startY = event.clientY - offsetY;
        scrollX= canvas?.scrollLeft as number;
        scrollY= canvas?.scrollTop as number;
        console.log(startX,startY);
        mousedown = true;
        console.log(event)
    };

    const handleMouseUp = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        mousedown = false;
    };

    const handleMouse = (event: MouseEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        mousex = event.clientX - offsetX;
        mousey = event.clientY - offsetY;
        if (mousedown) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('snip') as HTMLCanvasElement;
            var ctx = canvas?.getContext('2d');
            ctx?.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            color = 'black';
            width= mousex - startX;
            height= mousey - startY;
            ctx?.strokeRect(startX ,startY, width , height );
        }
    };

    function handleClick() {
        // captureScreenshot(0, 0, 500, 500);

        const element = document.createElement('canvas');
        element.style.position = 'absolute';
        element.style.top = '0';
        element.style.left = '0';
        element.style.height = '100%';
        element.style.width = '100%';
        element.style.zIndex = '10';
        element.id = 'snip';
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
        element.addEventListener('mouseup',handleMouseUp);
        element.addEventListener('mousemove',handleMouse);
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
```